# How to find the steady state probabilites

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

A particle moves in a circle from points $0,1,2,3,4$ (in a clockwise order)
it moves one step clock wise with probability $q$ and one step counter clockwise with probability $(1-q)$.

Let $X_n$ denote its location in the circle ($\{X_n:n\geqslant 0\}$ is a Markov chain).

How do I find the steady state probabilities considering the particle is always moving?

I started by finding the transition matrix but I don't know where to go from there;

$$\begin{pmatrix}0&q&0&0&1-q\\ 1-q&0&q&0&0\\ 0&1-q&0&q&0\\ 0&0&1-q&0&q\\ q&0&0&1-q&0\end{pmatrix}.$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because this is a doubly stochastic matrix (both the rows and the columns sum to one, the unique stationary distribution is the uniform distribution over $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$. Indeed,
\begin{align}
&\quad\frac15\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1&1&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0&q&0&0&1-q\\ 1-q&0&q&0&0\\ 0&1-q&0&q&0\\ 0&0&1-q&0&q\\ q&0&0&1-q&0\end{pmatrix}\\
&=\begin{pmatrix}0&q&0&0&1-q\\ 1-q&0&q&0&0\\ 0&1-q&0&q&0\\ 0&0&1-q&0&q\\ q&0&0&1-q&0\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}